# TimeSeriesSplit for multiple features in training set

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, cross-validation

I am trying to use Time-Series Split to establish a training and testing dataset and encountered the problem that I can not incorporate two features in the training set. Use the code below would generate

> IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
    import quandl 
    AAPL = quandl.get('WIKI/AAPL')
    import pandas as pd

    start = '2016-1-1'
    end = '2016-12-31'
    df = pd.DataFrame([AAPL['Adj. Close']])
    df = df.transpose()
    df = df.loc['20160101':'20161231']

    df['Daily Return'] = df['Adj. Close'].pct_change()
    df['LogReturn'] = np.log(df['Adj. Close']/df['Adj. Close'].shift())
    df['Adj.Close_3_d'] = df['Adj. Close'].shift(3)
    df = df.dropna()

    y = df['Adj. Close']
    X = pd.DataFrame([df['LogReturn'], df['Adj.Close_3_d']]).transpose()

    tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)
    print(tscv)  

    for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
        print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Thus, I changed the iteration to:

```
        X_train, X_test = X[[train_index]], X[[test_index]]
```

The error this time became:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

What is the best way to make the index work and hashable? 
I am just start picking up basic programming concepts so any help would be deeply appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by setting up the indexing like below:

```
X_train, X_test = X[:len(train_index)], X[len(train_index): (len(train_index)+len(test_index))]
```